# Change all values of a pandas column to first occurrence if same value on another column

Tags: python, pandas, date

I want to change all the dates in the date column to the earliest date, if the text column is the same.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'text': ['I like python pandas', 
                                 'find all function input from help jupyter',
                                 'function input',
                           'function input',
                            'function input'],'date': ['March 1st',"March 2nd","March 3rd","March 4th","March 5th"]})
```

So March 4th and March 5th, I want to be changed to March 3rd, since it is the earliest occurrence when the text column has "function input," listed.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are the dates necessary to be in that format?

Comment: no, it does not have to be in this format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do :

```py
def update_col(col):
    col[:] = col.iloc[0]
    return col

df['date'] = df.groupby('text').date.apply(update_col)
df
#                                        text       date
# 0                       I like python pandas  March 1st
# 1  find all function input from help jupyter  March 2nd
# 2                             function input  March 3rd
# 3                             function input  March 3rd
# 4                             function input  March 3rd
```

Comment: did this work for you?  It is turning my whole column of dates into NaN.

Comment: I kind of made a mistake, I forgot to add the return on my util function, It should work fine now

Comment: glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

You can group by `text` and then join the result with the original. Something like:

```py
new_df = df.set_index('text').join(df.groupby('text').first(), lsuffix='_old')
```

Then `print(new_df)` shows:

```
                                            date_old       date
text                                                           
I like python pandas                       March 1st  March 1st
find all function input from help jupyter  March 2nd  March 2nd
function input                             March 3rd  March 3rd
function input                             March 4th  March 3rd
function input                             March 5th  March 3rd
```

Comment: Text only for this method, right?

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
df1 = df.drop_duplicates(['text'], keep = 'first')
del df['date']
df2 = pd.merge(df, df1, how = 'left', on = ['text'])
```

Output:

```
                                        text       date
0                       I like python pandas  March 1st
1  find all function input from help jupyter  March 2nd
2                             function input  March 3rd
3                             function input  March 3rd
4                             function input  March 3rd
```